# App name doesn't show on xcode console output

Tags: swift, xcode

My app name doesn't show on console when I run it. I wonder why?

This is the sample console output in my app:

```
Successfully set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
Use of audio session mode is disabled.
Successfully set overrideOutputAudioPort to 'none'
Current audio session category options: 4
```

and this is the other app's console using same SDK which shows the app name and timestamp at the beginning of console messages:

```
2017-09-01 15:13:48.763063-0700 SinchCalling[4246:2156734] Successfully set audio session category 'AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord'
2017-09-01 15:13:48.763150-0700 SinchCalling[4246:2156734] Use of audio session mode is disabled.
2017-09-01 15:13:48.763205-0700 SinchCalling[4246:2156734] Successfully set overrideOutputAudioPort to 'none'
2017-09-01 15:13:48.763260-0700 SinchCalling[4246:2156734] Current audio session category options: 4
```

I wonder why this happens. Is it because I do something wrong in my app or its nothing important?

and before my app starts this SDK I can see my app's name on console just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other app is likely using `NSLog()`, whereas your app is probably using `print()`. The former will log the app name and timestamp, whereas the latter will not.

Fortunately, although `NSLog()` is usually associated with Objective-C code, it's also available in Swift, so you can use it for all your logging needs.